# PHPで3DES-CBCで暗号化されたデータを復号したい

Tags: php, security

開発言語はPHPです。

データは以下のアルゴリズムで暗号化されています。
3DES-CBC(Paddingなし)
Padding文字列：半角スペース

１、暗号化
Padding処理
自動Paddingなしなので最後の８バイトブロックに対して必要な分だけ半角スペースで埋める

3DES-CBC
秘密キーと初期化ベクトル(iv)で暗号化

BASE64エンコード

２、復号化
上記の逆なので
BASE64デコード

3DES-CBC復号化

空白を除去

で良いと思うのですが、以下のような感じで良いのでしょうか？

```
$encrypt;  //暗号化されたデータ

//BASE64デコード
$data = base64_decode($encrypt);

$des;　//秘密キー
$iv;　 //初期化ベクトル(iv)

//使用するアルゴリズムおよびモードのモジュールをオープン
$em = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

// 暗号化に必要な全てのバッファを初期化
mcrypt_generic_init($em, $des, $iv);

//復号化する
$decode = mdecrypt_generic($em, $data);

//空白を除去する
$result = trim($decode);
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問の意図がよくわかりません。暗号化/復号できるかどうかは実際に試せば分かるのでは？

Comment: h2so5さん
暗号化仕様が提示されているので、今後復号部を実装していきます。
復号化に関して実装するのは初めてです。
なのでそもそもどういう手順で実装すれば良いかを知りたかったのです。
お言葉通り試してみれば良いのですが、復号できなかったときに、APIの使い方なのか、手順が間違ってるのか切り分けが必要になってきます。
なので事前に手順だけでも確認したいと思って質問しました。

Comment: @h2so5 さんの言うとおり、試したほうが良いです。
一度動かして頂いたほうが、その結果ありきでお話できるので具体的かつ建設的なアドバイスもできると思います。

Comment: @Shironeさん 了解です。まずは現在の私の理解の範囲で実装、動かしてみて、その結果にしたがって質問させていただきたいと思います